# Ajustar posição de Div no CSS e HTML

Tags: html5, css3

Possuo um relatório que é montado em html e css no tamanho da folha A4 no formato paisagem. Tudo funciona perfeito. No entanto não consigo alinhar as tabelas uma do lado da outra.
Quero Alinhar todas as tabelas (divs) abaixo uma do lado da outra:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

CSS:

```
 body {
        background: rgb(204, 204, 204);
    }

page {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
}

    page[size="A4"] {
        width: 21cm;
        height: 29.7cm;
    }

        page[size="A4"][layout="portrait"] {
            width: 29.7cm;
            height: 21cm;
        }

@media print {
    body,
    page {
        margin: 0;
        box-shadow: 0;
    }
}

.header {
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid #ddd;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 80%;
}

    table th {
        background-color: #4caf50;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
    }

th,
td {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    text-align: left;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #f2f2f2
}

/* para definir a impressão no modo paisagem */
@page {
    size: landscape
}
.relativeEsquerda {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    border: solid #6AC5AC 3px;
}

.relativeProcesso {
    position: relative;
    left: 300px;
    width: 600px;
    height: auto;
    border: solid #6AC5AC 3px;
}

.relativeDireita {
    position: relative;
    left: 600px;
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    border: solid #6AC5AC 3px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="~/Areas/Qualidade/Css/RelatorioPaisagem.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="a4_vertical">
        <page size="A4">
            <img src="~/imagem/logo.png" />
            <div class="header">

                <h3>[DIAGRAMA DE PROCESSO] -  [QUALIDADE]</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="relativeEsquerda">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Recursos de Materiais </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @{ for (int i = 0; i < ViewBag.listaMaterial.Count; i++)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>@ViewBag.listaMaterial[i].Descricao</td>
                                </tr>
                                cont++;
                            }
                        }

                </table>

                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Interface Entrada </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @{ for (int i = 0; i < ViewBag.listaEntrada.Count; i++)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>@ViewBag.listaEntrada[i].Descricao</td>
                                </tr>
                                cont++;
                            }
                        }

                </table>
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Métodos/Processo/Técnica </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @{ for (int i = 0; i < ViewBag.listaMetodo.Count; i++)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>@ViewBag.listaMetodo[i].Descricao</td>
                                </tr>
                                cont++;
                            }
                        }

                </table>

            </div>

            <div class="relativeProcesso">
              <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="2">PROCESSO </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @{ for (int i = 0; i < ViewBag.listaProcesso.Count; i++)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    @if(i == 0) {
                                         <td>P(Plan)</td>
                                    }
                                    <td>@ViewBag.listaProcesso[i].Plano</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    @if (i == 0)
                                    {
                                        <td>D(do)</td>
                                    }
                                    <td>@ViewBag.listaProcesso[i].Do_</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    @if (i == 0)
                                    {
                                        <td>C(Check)</td>
                                    }
                                    <td>@ViewBag.listaProcesso[i].Verifica</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    @if (i == 0)
                                    {
                                        <td>A(Action)</td>
                                    }
                                    <td>@ViewBag.listaProcesso[i].Acao</td>
                                </tr>
                                cont++;
                            }
                        }

</table>

            </div>
            <div class="relativeDireita">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Recursos de Pessoal </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @{ for (int i = 0; i < ViewBag.listaRecursoPessoal.Count; i++)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>@ViewBag.listaRecursoPessoal[i].Descricao</td>
                                </tr>
                                cont++;
                            }
                        }

                </table>

                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Interface Saída </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @{ for (int i = 0; i < ViewBag.listaSaida.Count; i++)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>@ViewBag.listaSaida[i].Descricao</td>
                                </tr>
                                cont++;
                            }
                        }

                </table>
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Medição/Monitoramento </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @{ for (int i = 0; i < ViewBag.listaMedicao.Count; i++)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>@ViewBag.listaMedicao[i].Descricao</td>
                                </tr>
                                cont++;
                            }
                        }

                </table>



            </div>


        </page>

        <page size="A4"></page>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Já tentou com float: left?

Comment: como ficaria? colocaria em todos os .relative?

Comment: parece que sim, se essas forem as divs principais da tabela.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vc pode colocar `display:inline-block` nas div e vc tem que tirar esses `left:300px / 600px`

Com essa regra vc pega todas as divs que começam com "rela" e coloca o `display` para ficarem em linha

```
[class^="rela"] { display: inline-block; }
```

Veja abaixo o código corrigido:

```css
 body {
        background: rgb(204, 204, 204);
    }

page {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
}

    page[size="A4"] {
        width: 21cm;
        height: 29.7cm;
    }

        page[size="A4"][layout="portrait"] {
            width: 29.7cm;
            height: 21cm;
        }

@media print {
    body,
    page {
        margin: 0;
        box-shadow: 0;
    }
}

.header {
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid #ddd;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 80%;
}

    table th {
        background-color: #4caf50;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
    }

th,
td {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    text-align: left;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #f2f2f2
}

/* para definir a impressão no modo paisagem */
@page {
    size: landscape
}
.relativeEsquerda {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    border: solid #6AC5AC 3px;
}

.relativeProcesso {
    position: relative;
    /* left: 300px; */
    width: 600px;
    height: auto;
    border: solid #6AC5AC 3px;
}

.relativeDireita {
    position: relative;
    /* left: 600px; */
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    border: solid #6AC5AC 3px;
}

[class^="rela"] {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="a4_vertical">
        <page size="A4">
            <img src="~/imagem/logo.png" />
            <div class="header">

                <h3>[DIAGRAMA DE PROCESSO] -  [QUALIDADE]</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="relativeEsquerda">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Recursos de Materiais </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                       
                                <tr>
                                    <td>@ViewBag.listaMaterial[i].Descricao</td>
                                </tr>
               
                </table>

                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Interface Entrada </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        
                                <tr>
                                    <td>@ViewBag.listaEntrada[i].Descricao</td>
                                </tr>
                           

                </table>
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Métodos/Processo/Técnica </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                       
                                <tr>
                                    <td>@ViewBag.listaMetodo[i].Descricao</td>
                                </tr>
                               

                </table>

            </div>

            <div class="relativeProcesso">
              <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="2">PROCESSO </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        
                                <tr>
                                   
                                         <td>P(Plan)</td>
                                    
                                    <td>@ViewBag.listaProcesso[i].Plano</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                   
                                        <td>D(do)</td>
                                    
                                    <td>@ViewBag.listaProcesso[i].Do_</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                   
                                        <td>C(Check)</td>
                                    
                                    <td>@ViewBag.listaProcesso[i].Verifica</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                   
                                        <td>A(Action)</td>
                                    
                                    <td>@ViewBag.listaProcesso[i].Acao</td>
                                </tr>
                       

</table>

            </div>
            <div class="relativeDireita">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Recursos de Pessoal </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                       
                                <tr>
                                    <td>@ViewBag.listaRecursoPessoal[i].Descricao</td>
                                </tr>
                               

                </table>

                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Interface Saída </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                       
                                <tr>
                                    <td>@ViewBag.listaSaida[i].Descricao</td>
                                </tr>
                                

                </table>
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Medição/Monitoramento </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                       
                                <tr>
                                    <td>@ViewBag.listaMedicao[i].Descricao</td>
                                </tr>
                                

                </table>



            </div>


        </page>

        <page size="A4"></page>
        </div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Vou testar ... Obrigada

Comment: @DanielleArrudatorres aqui testando no Chrome deu certo, mas testa ai para ver se não tem nenhum detalhe pra arrumar

Comment: Certinho... Obrigada. Agora vou ajustar layout pra ficar bonitinho. colocar logo, mudar cor... etc..

Comment: @DanielleArrudatorres isso ai, faz a "arte final" agora pra ficar legal, qq outra dúvida posta ai que sempre tem alguém pra ajudar []´s